# Pass variable from template to views after click on map

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm learning Django and have a problem with one task.
This is not a full task, it's just for me to understand the process (I tried to read documentation, but It didn't help).
So, I have a map (Leaflet) and function onMapClick.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [path('map/', mapper)]
```

I created a model to save data from template

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class MapHello(models.Model):
    p = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.p
```

I want to pass some data to views.py from template after clicking on map (after using onMapClick(e)) and add It to database.

As I understand, I should use AJAX. For now I have something that doesn't work. I tried to use AJAX:

```
# part of map_in.html
function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
                .openOn(mymap);
            var lat_lng = e.latlng

            $.ajax({
                url: "/map/",
                type: "get",
                data: {msg: "HELLO!!!!"},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.result);;
                }});
```

So I'm trying to send do views.py message "HELLO!!!!" after every click on the map.

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MapHello

def mapper(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        value = request.GET.get('msg')
        if value:
            MapHello.objects.create(p=value)
    return render(request, 'map_in.html')
```

But, as I can see, mapper don't get any data from template. So the problem is in AJAX? Or I somehow should use two views (one just for rendering page and second for getting and manipulating data from template)?

Or maybe all my code is wrong:) I'm just learning.

And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: So when you have some code snippets that dont work together you need to find the point where you get an error/unexpected behaviour. The proper way would be using a debugger, for the beginning you can try `console.log()/print()` to narrow down the problem. 1. Is `onMapClick` actually executed? 2. are you sending out a `http get request` (check in your terminal where you wrote `manage.py runserver`) 3.  is the `def mapper()` ever called and are the `if statements` ever `True`? use `print()` for the python parts, `console.log()` for `js`. Hope this helps you to solve some bugs

Comment: @hansTheFranz Thank for your advice!   1. 'onMapClick' executed (It shows window with coordinates); 2. In terminal I see 'GET /map/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1606';  3. 'def mapper()' called. I see, that function can't get any data ('print(value)' return None). So the problem is in AJAX?

Comment: very good, I am glad to hear this. your problem seems to be `request.GET.get('msg')` a way would be to `print(request.GET)` to have a look at what DOES come through and then work your way from here. my guess would be `value = request.GET['msg']`.

Comment: @hansTheFranz, `print(request.GET)` return `<QueryDict: {}>`. I tried to use your code, but I had an error `Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /map/
Exception Value: 'msg'`.